# How to add Search bar in top of a tabbed page in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, searchbar, tabbedpage

In my xamarin app,I want to add a search bar on top of the page in my tabbed page.

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="Sample.Mobile.Test">

   <StackLayout>
      <SearchBar></SearchBar>
   </StackLayout>
<TabbedPage.Children>
    <ContentPage x:Name="tab1" Title="Home">
  </ContentPage>

 </TabbedPage.Children>
</TabbedPage>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use follow this link for the Search bar Implementation
https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.SearchBar/

Comment: Need like facebook search bar

Comment: If you are talking about the smooth animation on click of the search bar in facebook You need to use Custom Renders.

Comment: Follow this link, 
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/28899/listview-search-bar